# React-Typescript: I want to register React event processing with addEventListener

Tags: typescript, types, react-typescript

### Question

I want to register an event with Type React.MouseEvent argument as listener of EventListener.
However, EventListener is accepting listeners of MouseEvent type, and it seems that an error occurs because the types do not match.
I know what caused the error, but I don't know how to match the types.

※I know that using the any type doesn't give an error, but I don't want to use it.

### Sample code

I want to display "move" on the console when I do mouseMove while mouseDown in the area inside the box (I use document.addEventListener because I want to detect mouseMove even in the area outside the box).

```
 const mouseSample: React.FC = () => {
      // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
      const [flag, setFlag] = useState(false);
      const handleMouseDown = (): void => {
        setFlag(true);
        document.addEventListener('mouseMove', handleMouseMove);//Error because the event type does not match
        document.addEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp);
      };
    
      const handleMouseMove = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>): void => {
        if (flag) {
          // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
          console.log('move');
        }
      };
    
      const handleMouseUp = (): void => {
        setFlag(false);
        document.removeEventListener('mouseMove', handleMouseMove);//Error because the event type does not match
        document.removeEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp);
      };
    
      return (
        <Box
          style={{
            height: '400px',
            width: '400px'
          }}
          onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
          onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}
          onMouseUp={handleMouseUp}
        >
          moveBox
        </Box>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here.  The first is a simple fix -- `'mouseMove'` needs to be  `'mousemove'` because event names are lowercase rather than camelCase.

The next one is harder as it involves the difference between the React synthetic event and the underlying DOM native event.  `handleMouseMove` expects a React synthetic event.  Presumably your `Box` component deals with synthetic events too.  But the `document` needs listeners for a native event.

You can get the native event from a synthetic event but not the other way around.  So your event handler should deal with the native event.  We use the type `MouseEvent` from the built-in DOM types.  Unlike the React event types, this `MouseEvent` is not generic.

```
const handleMouseMove = (event: MouseEvent): void => {
```

Now your `document` listeners are fine, but `Box` has a problem because `handleMouseMove` is not assignable to `onMouseMove`. To fix that, we can use an inline arrow function to go from the React synthetic event to native event.

```
onMouseMove={(e) => handleMouseMove(e.nativeEvent)}
```